# Route subpage to Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have an `artists-single.php` page template which shows when I navigate to:

```
/artists/djave_co
```

Is there a way to route

```
/artists/djave_co/anything
```

to the same `artists-single.php` page? Then I can use some PHP logic to deal with the rendering of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually struggle with this, however this time I managed it relatively easy. Main reference for this answer is here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

I'd like to use `anything` in the below as `discipline`.

```
/artists/djave_co/anything
```

First of all, I added a "rewrite tag"

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%discipline%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

Next, I did `print_r($wp_query->query_vars)` on the default custom post page. This resulted in the below:

```
Array
(
    [page] => 0
    [artists] => djave_co
    [post_type] => artists
    [name] => djave_co
    [error] => 
    ...
```

This helped me, as I could see that I'd need to set `post_type=artists&artists=djave_co` in the next step.

The next step was to add a custom rewrite rule:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule(
    '^artists/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?post_type=artists&artists=$matches[1]&discipline=$matches[2]',
    'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

The final and **very important step was to clear the permalinks in the WordPress admin panel.**